# SQL: Insert doesn't work

Tags: mysql, insert

```
insert into table (id, day) values (0, 'Monday');
```

I don't know why this isn't working. I mean, I am actually new to SQL, but it should work. At least in a tutorial it did.

Comment: Could you post the error you're getting?

Comment: Can  you post the exact SQL you're using and describe the table?

Comment: You should not use SQL keywords for names.  You didn't name your table "table", did you?  Is your dog named "dog"?  Change it to something else like "day_of_week" or something.  By the way: It's not important to anybody here.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table (id, day) values (0, 'Monday')' at line 1

Comment: Please describe the error you are recieving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...

In general, assuming that there is a table named `table` in your database, and the table `table` has 2 columns, `id` and `day`, the insert should work. If the table has additional columns, unless those columns are nullable or have a default constraint assigned, the insert will fail. However...

`table` is a SQL **keyword**, meaning it can't be used as a table name as you're doing in your example without quoting it. Not knowing what SQL dialect you're using...

- Standard (ANSI/ISO) SQL quotes keywords with double quotes:

  ```
  insert "table" (id,day) values(0,'Monday')
  ```
- T-SQL (Microsoft/Sybase SQL Server) accepts either double quotes as above or left/right square brackets:

  ```
  insert [table] (id,day) values(0,'Monday')
  ```

Further, some SQL dialects will require that the statement be terminated with `;`:

```
insert "table" (id,day) values(0,'Monday') ;
```

Even further, depending on your SQL implementation and your isolation level/transaction scope, you may have to explicitly `commit` your transaction to persist the change.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to change the table (from the syntax sample) to my table name. Thx. ^^

Answer (score 1):

`table` is a keyword in SQL.

Are you sure your table's name is `table`?

If yes, you must quote it like this :

```
insert into [table] (id, day) values (0, 'Monday');
```

But I suggest you to rename your table.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to use the right table name. I'm sorry.

Comment: But thanks for the quick help. ^^

Comment: The `[]` are not "SQL" quotes: they are a non-standard extension in SQL Server. The SQL standard requires double quotes for this kind of identifier